# All search engines replaced with Yahoo as well as home page

Tags: firefox, search, adware

While installing GOM player it occurred to my girlfriend to have all their search engines in deleted, replaced with Yahoo only. As well, the home page was replaced with Yahoo.

[image: image description]

The homepage is especially irritating as it's full of some crap news nobody has ever cared about and which take long to load and try to load on every new tab I ever open.

Removing the Yahoo search engine has no effect, neither has setting the Youtube as default. Google cannot even be added to search engines.

[image: image description]

So, to my question:

- How can I prevent the Yahoo from coming back as my home page?
- How can I remove Yahoo from search engines so that it won't appear again?
- How can I add Google to my search engines?

Some investigator might find the referal parameters of the homepage interesting:

`https://www.yahoo.com/?fr=vmn&type=vmn__webcompa__1_0__ya__hp_WCYID10099_swoc_campaign_150406__yaff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the **worst** thing that could happen to you as a result of bundleware/adware... But yes, annoying.  Try using [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds) to uninstall the toolbar and any associated applications, as well as the browser helpers/extensions that it might have added.  (See the "Tools / Startup" section of CCleaner for the latter.)  If that all fails, try [HijackThis](http://filehippo.com/download_hijackthis/), a powerful tool (but slightly more dangerous, just because you could accidentally remove something you needed) for removing browser-hijacks.  Good luck!

Comment: Alternatively, since you tagged this question with "firefox", you could try a simple profile-reset.  See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems

Comment: Ok, I found the malware that forced yahoo as default page and search engine after which CCleaner hepled with the rest, thanks. Any idea why I cannot add Google to the search engines?

Answer (score 1):

Go to add-on page and look for suspicious/strange extensions/addon and disable or remove them then restart firefox. There are a lot of malware extension that inject ads to homepage today.